# I am trying to write a custom Laravel function on boot, but I get errors

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to write the following function in the App Service Provider but am getting errors:

My code is:

```
public function boot()
{
    $homepage = 'https://example.com';
    $already_crawled = [];
    $crawling = [];

    function follow_links($url)
    {
        global $already_crawled;
        global $crawling;

        $doc = new \DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

        $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach ($linklist as $link) {
            $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
            $full_link = 'https://example.com' . $l;

            if (!in_array($full_link, $already_crawled)) {
                $already_crawled[] = $full_link;
                $crawling[] = $full_link;
                Log::info($full_link . PHP_EOL);
            }
        }

        array_shift($crawling);
        foreach ($crawling as $link) {
            follow_links($link);
        }
    }

    follow_links($homepage);
}
```

So with this code I am getting errors like:

in_array() expected parameter 2 to be array, null given

What should I do to run this without problems?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.1

Comment: What's your end goal with this code i.e. after you've logged the links what are you planning on doing with them?

Comment: I am planning to get data out of them and store it in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables in your `boot` function aren't `global`, so your `follow_links` function's globals are a totally separate set of variables. You should basically never have the keyword `global` anywhere in Laravel, ever.

Because of your scope issues, `$already_crawled` is undefined when you first attempt to feed it to `is_array`. Use class properties, and `$this` to access them. On top of that, I've removed the weird function-in-a-function construction:

```
protected $already_crawled;
protected $crawling;
protected $homepage;

public function boot()
{
    $this->homepage = 'https://example.com';
    $this->already_crawled = [];
    $this->crawling = [];

    $this->follow_links($this->homepage);
}

protected function follow_links($url)
{
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

    $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($linklist as $link) {
        $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
        $full_link = 'https://example.com' . $l;

        if (!in_array($full_link, $this->already_crawled)) {
            $this->already_crawled[] = $full_link;
            $this->crawling[] = $full_link;
            Log::info($full_link . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }

    array_shift($this->crawling);
    foreach ($this->crawling as $link) {
        $this->follow_links($link);
    }
}
```

Side note: You almost certainly **don't** want this in your service provider. It's going to make a HTTP `file_get_contents` call on **every single pageview your app ever serves**. It's going to slow your app down dramatically.

Comment: Can you tell me a better way to set this piece of code in my Laravel project? I really don't know here to put it and my "best" solution was to set it up in the boot function.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab It depends on why you're running this code. I can't really figure out what the point of this crawling is; you don't save the crawled data anywhere or really do anything with it at all.

Comment: The code is not yet complete. I will store data from the crawled urls in a database.